# How do you handle pluralisation in Ember?

Tags: ember.js

Are there any helpers for making templates aware of when to use plural words?

In the example below, how do you make the template output "2 dogs have..."?

The code:

```
Ember.View.create({dog_count: 2})
```

The template:

```
{{dog_count}} (dog has)/(dogs have) gone for a walk.
```

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48726/best-javascript-i18n-techniques-ajax-dates-times-numbers-currency

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I know this is old, but I needed it today, so here goes.

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('pluralize', function(number, opts) {
  var single = opts.hash['s'];
  Ember.assert('pluralize requires a singular string (s)', single);
  var plural = opts.hash['p'] || single + 's';
  return (number == 1) ? single : plural;
});
```

Usage:

```
{{questions.length}} {{pluralize questions.length s="Question"}}
```

or

```
{{dog_count}} {{pluralize dog_count s="dog has" p="dogs have"}} gone for a walk.
```

The plural (p=) option is only necessary when you don't want the standard +s behavior.

Comment: You win the prize for the correct simple answer.  These other guys tried hard, but that was in the days before `registerBoundHelper` existed.

Comment: This is not a good option, the more correct approach would be @Giovanni's. But since ember-inflector now registers a pluralize helper itself you get this out of the box (see https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-inflector/issues/18).

Comment: I've updated this to work in Ember 2.x, [here](https://gist.github.com/finferflu/8eeeff014acec7525f466aa72d0ab560), but since I don't know how named parameters work in there, I've opted for positional parameters. Feel free to improve it!

Answer (score 10):

There is a I18n library for Ember: [zendesk/ember-i18n](https://github.com/zendesk/ember-i18n).

There is a handlebars helper `t` which handles the internationalization by looking up string from `Em.I18n.translations`:

```js
Em.I18n.translations = {
  'dog.walk.one': '1 dog has gone for a walk.',
  'dog.walk.other': '{{count}} dogs have gone for a walk.'
};
```

And you can then use the string in your Handlebars template via:

```html
{{t dog.walk countBinding="dogCount"}}
```

The code above is untested and just taken from the documentation in the [README](https://github.com/zendesk/ember-i18n#readme).

---

Another JS I18n library I found is Alex Sexton's [messageformat.js](https://github.com/SlexAxton/messageformat.js).

---

It depends on the complexity of you app, but you can also use a computed property for that, see http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/pzg4c/:

**Handlebars**:

```html
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="dog" >
    {{dogCountString}}
</script>​
```

**JavaScript**:

```js
Ember.View.create({
    templateName: 'dog',
    dogCountString: function() {
        var dogCount = this.get('dogCount');
        var dogCountStr = (dogCount === 1) ? 'dog has' : 'dogs have';
        return '%@ %@ gone for a walk.'.fmt(dogCount, dogCountStr);
    }.property('dogCount')
}).append();
```

Comment: shouldn't it a better solution to create a handlebars helper instead of a computed property directly ?

Comment: I found an I18n library for Ember which has a handlebars helper.

Answer (score 9):

If you use Ember Data you can use `Ember.Inflector`.

```
var inflector = new Ember.Inflector(Ember.Inflector.defaultRules);

inflector.pluralize('person') //=> 'people'
```

You can register a new helper with:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('pluralize', function(number, single) {
  if (number === 1) { return single; }
  else {
    var inflector = new Ember.Inflector(Ember.Inflector.defaultRules);
    return inflector.pluralize(single);
  }
});
```

More details at http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/Ember.Inflector.html

Comment: ember-inflector now registers a pluralize helper itself you get this out of the box (see https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-inflector/issues/18).

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you [got an answer from wycats himself](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/issues/249#issuecomment-6003750), but I didn't see it mentioned in this thread, so here it is:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('pluralize', function(number, single, plural) {
    if (number === 1) { return single; }
    else { return plural; }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I recently found this library http://slexaxton.github.com/Jed/ which seems to be a nice tool for JS i18n. I guess you can pretty easily create your own implementation by registering a handlebars helper using this library.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of any Ember specific functions that will do this for you. However, generally when you pluralize a word, the single version only shows up when the count is one.

See this for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/6VN56/

```
function pluralize(count, single, plural) {
    return count + " " + (count == 1 ? single : plural);
}

pluralize(1, 'dog', 'dogs') // 1 dog
pluralize(10, 'dog', 'dogs') // 10 dogs
pluralize(0, 'dog', 'dogs') // 0 dogs
```